# React Native Navigation - Invalid hook call

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import Stack from "./navigation/Stack";

export default function App() {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(true);
  const onFinish = () => setIsReady(true);
  return isReady ? (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  ) : (
      <Text>Loading...</Text>
    );
}
```

Trying to navigate to a screen through a custom component:

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import Home from "../screens/Home";
import Detail from "../screens/Detail";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default () => (
    <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Detail" component={Detail} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

Im getting an error:

> Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called
> inside of the body of a function component.

Can someone have a look on it?

Comment: can you show us the code for the custom component ?

Comment: second code is custom component

Comment: nothing wrong in this code, you are probably using a hook somewhere else maybe in Home or Detail page

Comment: this code is valid, you should put more code and where it is triggered